# CodeIgniter: stream socket enable crypto SSL/TLS already set-up for this stream warning

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl, amazon-web-services

I get a PHP warning (`stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL/TLS already set-up for this stream`) when I send an email using the [codeigniter email library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) from my [Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) [VirtualBox VM](https://www.virtualbox.org/) via my [AWS SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).  The **email is successfully sent** in spite of the warning.

```
// /application/config/email.php:
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'OMITTED';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'OMITTED';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = true;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
```

My code to send the email is nothing fancy at this point:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('team@omitted.com', 'Team Omitted');
$this->email->to($person[0]['email']);
$this->email->subject('Temporary password');
$this->email->message('Here is your temporary password:<br />'.$new_pw);

if($this->email->send())
    $return['success'] = true;
else
    $return['err_msg'] = 'Failed to send password reset email. Please try again';
```

What exactly is the warning telling me and how can I fix this? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this resolve the warning when trying to use SSL/TLS smtp crypto with Email librarie in CodeIgniter.

Open the file: /system/libraries/Email.php

Then, into the _smtp_connect() function, you would edit it as follows on the code:

```
if ($this->smtp_crypto == 'tls')
{
    $this->_send_command('hello');
    $this->_send_command('starttls');
    if( strpos( $this->smtp_host, 'ssl://') === FALSE ) {
      stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_smtp_connect, TRUE, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
    }
}
```

More Info for function stream_socket_enable_crypto: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-enable-crypto.php